# How to remove substring which is in a python list

Tags: python

how to remove substring which is in a python list? Below is the script which remove fruits that is not in the fruitChoice array. The expected output should "apple orange"

The code I have

```
fruits="banana melon apple orange peach"

def checksth(str):
    fruitChoice=["apple","orange"]
    for elem in str.split(" "):
        if elem not in fruitChoice:
           fruits_selected=fruits.replace(elem,"")

    return fruits_selected

print(checksth(fruits))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension for this,

```
fruits="banana melon apple orange peach"

def checksth(fruits):
    fruitChoice=["apple","orange"] 
    return [fruit for fruit in fruits.split() if fruit in fruitChoice]
print(checksth(fruits))
```

Comment: 3 small things. 1) str is a Python built-in and therefore not a good variable name 2) your function doesn't utilise the input parameter 3) your logic is inverted

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits= "banana melon apple orange tomato peach"

fruitChoice=["pinapple","advacado","orange","watermelon","dragonfruit","tomato","apple","honeydew"]

result=""
for fruit in fruits.split(" "):
    if fruit in fruitChoice:
        result=fruit+" "+result

print(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a `filter` case:

```py
def checksth(fruits_list):
    fruitChoice = ["apple", "orange"]
    return ' '.join(filter(lambda f: f in fruitChoice, fruits_list.split()))


fruits = "banana melon apple orange peach"
print(checksth(fruits))
```